# Package fontspec Error: The font "HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md" cannot be found

Tags: fonts

how to add external font path in latex? when I compile the latex(texlive 2023) document in macOS 13.2, shows error:

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md" cannot be found.
```

I have already tried to put the font into the path and add the path like this:

```
\setmainfont[
Path = /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/texmf/tex/latex/Font,
Extension = .otf,
]{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md}
```

still could not fixed this issue. what should I do to add the font path in macOS? this is the folder font list:

```
> ll
total 48760
-rw-r--r--  1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    41K Jun 15 18:28 HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    34K Jun 15 18:28 HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf
-rw-r--r--  1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    12M Jun 15 18:28 Pro_GB18030.ttf
-rw-r--r--  1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    12M Jun 15 18:28 Pro_GB18030DemiBold.ttf
```

I have tried to copy the file to folder `~/Library/Fonts`, still could not fixed this issue.

Comment: You may need file name not font name.

Comment: That _is_ the file name ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the fonts into `/Users/.../Library/Fonts/HelveticaNeue/`
Then run in a terminal `luaotfload-tool --update`. Now the files should be listed with

```
 luafindfont helveticaneue
```

e.g.:

```
bash-3.2$ luafindfont helveticaneueltpro
  No.                        Filename      Symbolic name                                  Path
   1.       HelveticaNeueLTPro-Bd.otf helveticaneueltpro  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Helvetica/
   2.     HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn.otf helveticaneueltpro  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Helvetica/
   3.    HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCnO.otf helveticaneueltpro  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Helvetica/
   4.     HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdEx.otf helveticaneueltpro  /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Helvetica/
 [...]
```

And `lualatex` or `xelatex` will find the fonts.